# python mongodb update_one preserve other values

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Let say collection is only one document

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5feaf2d41d368d7248a21662'), 
 'counter': {'tenders_daily': 0, 
             'tenders_weekly': 0, 
             'news_daily': 0, 
             'news_weekly': 0
            }
}
```

How can I in python3 update_one only one value, let say 'tenders_weekly' to 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
collection.update_one({ '_id': ObjectId('5feaf2d41d368d7248a21662') }, { "$set": { 'counter.tenders_weekly': 5 } } )
```

Comment: I am not sure, new to mongodb, but this will create second key besides counter I think

Comment: The above solution will work it will only update tenders_weekly field

Comment: It will do exactly what you need , it will update only the tenders_weekly value  inside the counter ...

Comment: Yes, I've tested it, it looks perfect! Thanks, will accept answer in 2 minutes